# C# Interop Word Insert File without Replacing

Tags: c#, html, file, ms-word, ms-office

I'm working on a **Word AddIn** in which I programmatically insert a file (with the Range.**InsertFile** method) into the active document (which is not saved yet). The problem is that this method **replaces** everything that's already in the document. As a user I want to be able to write some text, then insert the file after the text, or even better wherever I want, possibly at the **cursor position**.

I thought about making the content temporarily *readonly* so that it wouldn't be replaced, but that seems to be too complicated. The **InsertAfter** Extension of Range does exactly what I want, just not with a file. The file is html by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Collapse the range first.

```
Range range = ...
range.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd); // defaults to wdCollapseStart if you omit this
```